# task error because symlink creation failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My Hadoop cluster is running on 8 CentOS 6.3 machines and the Hadoop version is CDH 4.3 (installed from Coludera Manager 4.6).
Recently I found that some of my jobs had failed tasks. The failed tasks will success in the next attempt. However, the failed tasks are so many ( 50000 tasks, 1000 failed ) and I'm afraid this will cause performance issue or other potential issue.
All of the failed tasks have the same call stack:

```
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:250)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Creation of symlink from /var/log/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/userlogs/job_201311140947_0002/attempt_201311140947_0002_m_051950_0 to /hdfs7/mapred/local/userlogs/job_201311140947_0002/attempt_201311140947_0002_m_051950_0 failed.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.createTaskAttemptLogDir(TaskLog.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.createLogDir(DefaultTaskController.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.prepareLogFiles(TaskRunner.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:215)
```

I tried to build the symlink manually on the same path and I encountered no problems. I'm wondering what cause this issue.